# Convergence to a fixed value

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, numerical-linear-algebra, stability-theory

This question is a follow up on the question about [marginal stability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969638/marginal-stability-of-discrete-linear-time-invariant-system) of LTI system:
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{x}[k] = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}[k-1]
\end{equation}
I am interested in the algorithm:

1. $k := 0$
2. $\mathbf{x}[0] := \mathbf{x}_0$
3. $k := k + 1$
4. $\mathbf{x}[k] := \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}[k-1]$
5. if $\lVert\mathbf{x}[k+1] - \mathbf{x}[k+1]\rVert > \varepsilon$ go to step 3

where $\varepsilon$ is a small value, e.g. $\varepsilon = 10^{-16}$.
I am assuming that the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ has eigenvalues on the unit circle.
This means that the system can be marginally stable at best, and not asymptotically stable.
I am interested what are the conditions for above algorithm to terminate.

The following examples show that the marginal stability is not enough.
An example of marginally stable matrix for which above algorithm doesn't converge is:
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
The above matrix has two complex eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2} = \pm j$.
The algorithm above will have a bounded oscillation and never finish with the iteration in the case of the presented matrix.

I don't think that complex eigenvalues are the problem since marginally stable matrix:
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
will also cause the above algorithm to oscillate with values $-x_0$ and $x_0$.

The algorithm will converge with an identity matrix $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{I}$.

Are the eigenvalues of $1$ only ones allowed on the unit circle for the above algorithm to terminate?
Is there some definition of stability that says that the above system is stable, but doesn't oscillate?
Any answer and/or reference request would be helpful.

Comment: You should learn about the Jordan canonical form. The answer to your questions (this one and the other, which really are the same) is then immediate.

Comment: @JohnB: I think I got it in the meanwhile. If Jordan decomposition is applied to matrix $\mathbf{A}$ than eigenvalues on the unit circle should be matched to diagonal Jordan blocks. All the eigenvalues on the unit circle are equal $e^{j\varphi}$ and each multiplication of the $\mathbf{A}$ by itself rotates the corresponding eigenvalue for $\varphi$. The only case when there will be no bounded oscillations is $1 = e^{j\varphi}\lvert_{\varphi = 0}$. Could you, please, confirm my reasoning. If I am correct, I am going to answer my own question.

Comment: More or less, the other matter is that of the multiplicity (see the answer to your other question).